# Change name of the commit without force

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm looking for a way for change a name of commit which is pushed.
But I can't use rebase or push with force.
Is it possible ?

Comment: By “name of commit”, do you mean the author’s name? (If so, the answer is no. That information is part of the commit and can’t be replaced without replacing the commit, which requires a force push.)

Comment: ... or commit message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change anything in a commit, by any normal means, regardless of whever it is pushed or not. Commit is done.

What you can do, and what sometimes is called 'changing a commit', is to COPY the commit's contents, alter it in some way, and then make another commit with altered contents. To make it look as a replacement, the new-copy must be properly located at the same place in the commit tree, not as a child of the old commit. Assume `MyWork` is the name of your branch:

```
was:
old5-old4-old3-old2-old1[MyWork]

NOT just new commit:
old5-old4-old3-old2-old1-newCopyOf1[MyWork]

but rather, a 'brother' of old commit:
                   /-old1[MyWork]
old5-old4-old3-old2
                   \-newCopyOf1(not under old1, but not in MyWork either)
```

Easiest way to do that, if it's immediately-most-recent-commit, it just `amend` it.

Of course if the commit to be 'replaced' is further down in the history, the harder it is to make it. That's where tools like `rebase` help, sometimes.

After you copy the commit and position it properly, you can for example push that new altered commit to the server, and then you can for example order the server to relabel branches so that the branch-of-your-interest points to that new commit instead of where it pointed before.

```
                   /-old1[<deletemeplease?>]
old5-old4-old3-old2
                   \-newCopyOf1[MyWork]
```

That's what you probably want to achieve.

Depending on whever the new-altered commit is a child of previous tip of the target branch, or whever it is a not-a-child of a previous tip of the branch, such action can be done by "normal push" or "push with force".

Doing a rebase boils down to the same basic things, just with a bit different workflow and more options automating some tasks.

If you cannot do a pushforce/rebase, then you cannot update the target branch to a commit that is not a child of that branch's current state. The server will check if commits grow "sideways" instead "further" and will stop you when it detects it.

However, there may be some indirect ways to get the same result. It still required you to make a new, altered commit, though. Nothing changes in the basic things.

For example, if you only want to undo some changes, you can just use `revert`. It won't change the history and the old commit will still be visible so probably it's not what you want.

For example, can you ... freely create branches? Then just do the alterations and push it as a new branch, forget the old branch with bad code, and work now under a new branch name and work on it.

```
                   /-old1[MyWork]
old5-old4-old3-old2
                   \-newCopyOf1[myNewBrach]
```

Yeah, that's not perfect. But now, another thing: can you freely delete a branch? Sometimes the server denies you push+force, but allows deleting branches. Then, do push the altered version as a new branch, and just delete the old one. If noone else was fast enough to download it or start a new work/branch on it, it will be lost.

```
                   /-old1
old5-old4-old3-old2
                   \-newCopyOf1[myNewBrach]
```

If you can create/delete branches, then you can also orchestrate it so that you end up with the same branch name as it was previously, just by more wiggling with branch names a bit.

```
                   /-old1(still there, but now invisible)
old5-old4-old3-old2
                   \-newCopyOf1[MyWork] (it's new branch, but old name, who cares!)
```

But that's probably as much as it's possible. It all depends on what exactly the server allows you to do.

And, I will state that again, if ANYONE did ANYTHING basing on that `old1` commit, and if anyone already has it in their history, then it is MUCH more hard, as you will have to synchronize with them and do cleanups/rewrites in their local histories as well to eradicate any ghosts of `old1` cloned into others' working copies.. that's why all those the sayings about not-amending commits that were already pushed.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a way for change a name of commit which is pushed. But I can't use rebase or push with force. Is it possible ?

No, it is not possible.  The only way to "change" anything about a commit is to make a changed copy (sometimes called "rewriting" the commit), and if you then want that copy (instead of the original) to be part of a branch, then the branch would have to be force pushed.

If you can't force push - and there are good reasons why you may not be able to - then you won't be able to erase the error from the branch's history.  It sounds like the error is in the commit metadata rather than the actual content, so even making new commits probably isn't helpful.  So what can you do?

You can add a note or an annotated tag to the commit to explain what's wrong.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag